resignFirstResponder() result in removeFromSuperview
I'm working on preexistent code.
I have a textfield inside a section of my tableview, anyway I try to hide the keyboard it ends up removing my view from the superview.
By adding a breakpoint inside the removeFromSuperview() I can see the resignFirstResponder() is the cause of it.

I can't find any explicit call to removeFromSuperview()
The table view is not realoding, because no UITableViewDatasource function is being executed
I registered the table view cell used as a section and dequeueReusableCell, I also tried calling it directly with Bundle.main.loadNib
I also tried hiding the keyboard using the UIApplication singleton to see if it acted the same, and it did.

ParentTableViewController

The first section doesn't exist, that's why its height is zero
The table view is built so there's a cellOne, section and cellTwo
the last cell (cellTwo) is another TableView, when I scroll, the section stays as a header

extension ParentTableViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
return 2
}
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return section == 0 ? 0 : 105
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        guard section == 1 else { return nil }
        let headerView = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SectionWithTextfieldCell.identifier) as! SectionWithTextfieldCell
        headerView.delegate = self
        headerView.setupUI(segmentIndexSelected: segmentIndexSelected, membersCount: campData.attributes?.members_count ?? 0, searchedText: viewModel?.searchUsername)
        return headerView
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                   cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: OtherCellOne.identifier) as! OtherCellOne
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.setup(campData: campData, descriptionLblLines: descriptionLblLines, segmentIndexSelected: segmentIndexSelected)
            return cell
        default:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: OtherCellTwo.identifier, for: indexPath) as! OtherCellTwo
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.setup(campData: campData, members: members, rooms: rooms, segmentIndexSelected: segmentIndexSelected, loadingUsers: viewModel?.loadingUsers)
            return cell
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 1:
            return heightMembersRooms
        default:
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        switch indexPath.section {
        case 1:
            return heightMembersRooms
        default:
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        }
    }
}

SectionWithTextfieldCell
class SectionWithTextfieldCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBarTrailingConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIButton!

    weak var delegate: Delegate?

    static var identifier: String {
        String(describing: self)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
    @IBAction func pressedCancel(_ sender: Any) {
        resetSearch() { [weak self] in
            guard let self else { return }
            searchBar.searchTextField.text = ""
            delegate?.search(username: "")
        }
    }

    func setupUI(segmentIndexSelected: Int, membersCount: Int, searchedText: String?) {
        searchBar.searchTextField.text = searchedText
        setupSearchBar()
    }

    func setupSearchBar() {
        searchBar?.delegate = self
        searchBar?.backgroundImage = UIImage()
        searchBar?.placeholder = String(localized: "Search for users by username...")
        searchBar?.clipsToBounds = true
        searchBar?.searchTextField.textColor = UIColor.init(hexString: "#585858")
        searchBar?.searchTextField.font = FontKit.roundedFont(ofSize: 15, weight: .regular)
        searchBar?.searchTextField.layer.cornerRadius = 25
        searchBar?.searchTextField.layer.masksToBounds = true
        searchBarTrailingConstraint.constant = 0
        cancelButton.setTitle(String(localized: "Cancel"), for: .normal)
        cancelButton.titleLabel?.font = FontKit.roundedFont(ofSize: 12, weight: .regular)
    }
    
    protocol Delegate: AnyObject {
        func search(username: String)
        func scrollToSearchBar()
    }
    
    func resetSearch(completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { [weak self] in
            guard let self else { return }
            searchBarTrailingConstraint.constant = 0
        }, completion: { [weak self] _ in
            guard let self else { return }
            searchBar.searchTextField.resignFirstResponder()
            completion?()
        })
    }
}


// MARK: - UISearchBarDelegate

extension SectionWithTextfieldCell: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        resetSearch()
    }
    
    func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: { [weak self] in
            guard let self else { return }
            searchBarTrailingConstraint.constant = cancelButton.frame.width
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
        delegate?.scrollToSearchBar()
        return true
    }
    
    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
        delegate?.search(username: searchText)
    }
}

